# Sitecore Solr DateTime range filter

Tags: indexing, solr, sitecore, multivalue

I want to create a custom index for query datetime range (Event datetime) in sitecore content search (SOLR).  I want to store datetime ranges like

```
 2010-01-01 - 2010-02-02
 2010-02-02 - 2011-03-21
....
```

and get items back as fast as possible. Is it possible to store multiple datetime ranges and use sitecore content search method to query for these items?

I create index field:

```
<field fieldName="Dates" returnType="tdate" multiValued="true" >Dummy.Core.Models.EventTime, Dummy.Core</field>
```

How can i implement a custom computed index ?
Somebody knows some basic tutorial for multiple value and date time ranges?
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Why don't you store "Start Date" and "End Date" individually? then you can query for items within this range, Here is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/a/21809659/1218297

Comment: There are multiple date times in the concept. There is an event like a movie.
Dates : 2011-01-01 - 2011-01-30
            2011-02-01 - 2011-02-22
I want to write an easy way to implement this and compress values to one field ( avoid big indexes ).

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution that i can think of it create schedule items under your event item, each schedule item has Start and End date, this way you can have as many schedules as possible, Then you can search on these schedules and get the parent item (Event).